# How to address out-of-sync distribution certificates in VS Mac vs. VS Windows?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-provisioning, code-signing-certificate

Ever since updating to Visual Studio for Windows 16.5, I've been unable to distribute iOS apps built in Visual Studio for Windows. On the Mac, my distribution certificate appears in Visual Studio for Mac v8.4.8 (2) (Preferences | Apple Developer Accounts | View Details) as "Valid". But in Windows (Tools | Options | Xamarin | Apple Accounts | View Details), the same certificate shows as "Not In Keychain". What does this mean and how can it be resolved?

Comment: Hi , do you select the **Manual Provisioning** to check whether provisioning file exists, you also can share a screenshot here to check .